# Docker (daemon) on Windows 10 crashing when started: "hnsCall failed in Win32: The service has not been started", while hns service is happily running

Tags: docker, windows-10

I can't get docker to work on my Windows 10 machine all of a sudden, the docker daemon won't start. I can't seem to figure out what's going on, the debug output tells me that the hns service has not been started, but it is running.

> This seems to only happen when I'm "switched" to running Windows containers, when I re-installed docker and it was running Linux containers, it seemed to work fine.

Ignore that (spoiler? SO doesn't want strikethrough text I guess), I just switched back to Linux containers and now get the same error.

This is the output of running dockerd from command line (with debug = true)

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources
λ dockerd
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.425145500Z" level=info msg="Starting up"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.428147300Z" level=debug msg="Listener created for HTTP on npipe (//./pipe/docker_engine)"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.432148800Z" level=info msg="Windows default isolation mode: hyperv"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.432148800Z" level=debug msg="Stackdump - waiting signal at Global\\stackdump-19544"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.433145200Z" level=debug msg="Using default logging driver json-file"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.433145200Z" level=debug msg="[graphdriver] trying provided driver: windowsfilter"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.433145200Z" level=debug msg="WindowsGraphDriver InitFilter at C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.434161600Z" level=debug msg="Initialized graph driver windowsfilter"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.441159100Z" level=debug msg="Max Concurrent Downloads: 3"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.441159100Z" level=debug msg="Max Concurrent Uploads: 5"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.441159100Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.442144600Z" level=debug msg="Option Experimental: false"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.442144600Z" level=debug msg="Option DefaultDriver: nat"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.442144600Z" level=debug msg="Option DefaultNetwork: nat"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.442144600Z" level=debug msg="Network Control Plane MTU: 1500"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.442144600Z" level=info msg="Restoring existing overlay networks from HNS into docker"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.442144600Z" level=debug msg="[GET]=>[/networks/] Request : "
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.447147300Z" level=debug msg="Network Response : [{\"ActivityId\":\"9A83FF02-21EB-49F0-879B-559444E6EC70\",\"AdditionalParams\":{},\"CurrentEndpointCount\":0,\"Extensions\":[{\"Id\":\"E7C3B2F0-F3C5-48DF-AF2B-10FED6D72E7A\",\"IsEnabled\":false,\"Name\":\"Microsoft Windows Filtering Platform\"},{\"Id\":\"E9B59CFA-2BE1-4B21-828F-B6FBDBDDC017\",\"IsEnabled\":false,\"Name\":\"Microsoft Azure VFP Switch Extension\"},{\"Id\":\"EA24CD6C-D17A-4348-9190-09F0D5BE83DD\",\"IsEnabled\":false,\"Name\":\"Microsoft NDIS Capture\"}],\"Flags\":0,\"Health\":{\"LastErrorCode\":0,\"LastUpdateTime\":132169931612174261},\"ID\":\"D63871DB-DF27-4EE6-80FB-6986CA4FDD2A\",\"IPv6\":false,\"LayeredOn\":\"7B01AE19-872A-416D-BA15-AF5CECD5F9E6\",\"MacPools\":[{\"EndMacAddress\":\"00-15-5D-74-AF-FF\",\"StartMacAddress\":\"00-15-5D-74-A0-00\"}],\"MaxConcurrentEndpoints\":0,\"Name\":\"My New Virtual Switch\",\"Policies\":[],\"State\":1,\"TotalEndpoints\":0,\"Type\":\"Transparent\",\"Version\":42949672963,\"Resources\":{\"AdditionalParams\":{},\"AllocationOrder\":0,\"CompartmentOperationTime\":0,\"Flags\":0,\"Health\":{\"LastErrorCode\":0,\"LastUpdateTime\":132169931612174261},\"ID\":\"9A83FF02-21EB-49F0-879B-559444E6EC70\",\"PortOperationTime\":0,\"State\":1,\"SwitchOperationTime\":0,\"VfpOperationTime\":0,\"parentId\":\"18DF5BED-03C6-4825-88D8-90F4DCB5473E\"}}]"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.449146500Z" level=debug msg="Network  transparent (1c2f3a6) restored"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.462148900Z" level=debug msg="[GET]=>[/networks/] Request : "
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.466149300Z" level=debug msg="Network Response : [{\"ActivityId\":\"9A83FF02-21EB-49F0-879B-559444E6EC70\",\"AdditionalParams\":{},\"CurrentEndpointCount\":0,\"Extensions\":[{\"Id\":\"E7C3B2F0-F3C5-48DF-AF2B-10FED6D72E7A\",\"IsEnabled\":false,\"Name\":\"Microsoft Windows Filtering Platform\"},{\"Id\":\"E9B59CFA-2BE1-4B21-828F-B6FBDBDDC017\",\"IsEnabled\":false,\"Name\":\"Microsoft Azure VFP Switch Extension\"},{\"Id\":\"EA24CD6C-D17A-4348-9190-09F0D5BE83DD\",\"IsEnabled\":false,\"Name\":\"Microsoft NDIS Capture\"}],\"Flags\":0,\"Health\":{\"LastErrorCode\":0,\"LastUpdateTime\":132169931612174261},\"ID\":\"D63871DB-DF27-4EE6-80FB-6986CA4FDD2A\",\"IPv6\":false,\"LayeredOn\":\"7B01AE19-872A-416D-BA15-AF5CECD5F9E6\",\"MacPools\":[{\"EndMacAddress\":\"00-15-5D-74-AF-FF\",\"StartMacAddress\":\"00-15-5D-74-A0-00\"}],\"MaxConcurrentEndpoints\":0,\"Name\":\"My New Virtual Switch\",\"Policies\":[],\"State\":1,\"TotalEndpoints\":0,\"Type\":\"Transparent\",\"Version\":42949672963,\"Resources\":{\"AdditionalParams\":{},\"AllocationOrder\":0,\"CompartmentOperationTime\":0,\"Flags\":0,\"Health\":{\"LastErrorCode\":0,\"LastUpdateTime\":132169931612174261},\"ID\":\"9A83FF02-21EB-49F0-879B-559444E6EC70\",\"PortOperationTime\":0,\"State\":1,\"SwitchOperationTime\":0,\"VfpOperationTime\":0,\"parentId\":\"18DF5BED-03C6-4825-88D8-90F4DCB5473E\"}}]"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.468145600Z" level=debug msg="Launching DNS server for network \"none\""
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.477145800Z" level=debug msg="releasing IPv4 pools from network My New Virtual Switch (1c2f3a6ce8a7445896145d15e265b9eda4095d6f35c71ad872f3e733059940c6)"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.477145800Z" level=debug msg="ReleasePool(0.0.0.0/0)"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.480145100Z" level=debug msg="cleanupServiceDiscovery for network:1c2f3a6ce8a7445896145d15e265b9eda4095d6f35c71ad872f3e733059940c6"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.486145500Z" level=debug msg="Allocating IPv4 pools for network My New Virtual Switch (1c2f3a6ce8a7445896145d15e265b9eda4095d6f35c71ad872f3e733059940c6)"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.486145500Z" level=debug msg="RequestPool(LocalDefault, , , map[], false)"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.486145500Z" level=debug msg="RequestAddress(0.0.0.0/0, <nil>, map[RequestAddressType:com.docker.network.gateway])"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.487161600Z" level=debug msg="[GET]=>[/endpoints/] Request : "
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.493144800Z" level=debug msg="Launching DNS server for network \"My New Virtual Switch\""
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.493144800Z" level=debug msg="[GET]=>[/networks/D63871DB-DF27-4EE6-80FB-6986CA4FDD2A] Request : "
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.497146600Z" level=debug msg="Network Response : {\"ActivityId\":\"9A83FF02-21EB-49F0-879B-559444E6EC70\",\"AdditionalParams\":{},\"CurrentEndpointCount\":0,\"Extensions\":[{\"Id\":\"E7C3B2F0-F3C5-48DF-AF2B-10FED6D72E7A\",\"IsEnabled\":false,\"Name\":\"Microsoft Windows Filtering Platform\"},{\"Id\":\"E9B59CFA-2BE1-4B21-828F-B6FBDBDDC017\",\"IsEnabled\":false,\"Name\":\"Microsoft Azure VFP Switch Extension\"},{\"Id\":\"EA24CD6C-D17A-4348-9190-09F0D5BE83DD\",\"IsEnabled\":false,\"Name\":\"Microsoft NDIS Capture\"}],\"Flags\":0,\"Health\":{\"LastErrorCode\":0,\"LastUpdateTime\":132169931612174261},\"ID\":\"D63871DB-DF27-4EE6-80FB-6986CA4FDD2A\",\"IPv6\":false,\"LayeredOn\":\"7B01AE19-872A-416D-BA15-AF5CECD5F9E6\",\"MacPools\":[{\"EndMacAddress\":\"00-15-5D-74-AF-FF\",\"StartMacAddress\":\"00-15-5D-74-A0-00\"}],\"MaxConcurrentEndpoints\":0,\"Name\":\"My New Virtual Switch\",\"Policies\":[],\"State\":1,\"TotalEndpoints\":0,\"Type\":\"Transparent\",\"Version\":42949672963,\"Resources\":{\"AdditionalParams\":{},\"AllocationOrder\":0,\"CompartmentOperationTime\":0,\"Flags\":0,\"Health\":{\"LastErrorCode\":0,\"LastUpdateTime\":132169931612174261},\"ID\":\"9A83FF02-21EB-49F0-879B-559444E6EC70\",\"PortOperationTime\":0,\"State\":1,\"SwitchOperationTime\":0,\"VfpOperationTime\":0,\"parentId\":\"18DF5BED-03C6-4825-88D8-90F4DCB5473E\"}}"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.507147200Z" level=debug msg="Allocating IPv4 pools for network nat (4456741d2c4fe47a5034db26ad9b1161c24ac18105ca4a71cf23cbe4fc6e3e88)"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.507147200Z" level=debug msg="RequestPool(LocalDefault, , , map[], false)"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.507147200Z" level=debug msg="RequestAddress(0.0.0.0/0, <nil>, map[RequestAddressType:com.docker.network.gateway])"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.507147200Z" level=debug msg="HNSNetwork Request ={\"Name\":\"nat\",\"Type\":\"nat\",\"Subnets\":[{\"AddressPrefix\":\"0.0.0.0/0\"}]} Address Space=[{0.0.0.0/0  []}]"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:23.507147200Z" level=debug msg="[POST]=>[/networks/] Request : {\"Name\":\"nat\",\"Type\":\"nat\",\"Subnets\":[{\"AddressPrefix\":\"0.0.0.0/0\"}]}"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:24.277127400Z" level=debug msg="releasing IPv4 pools from network nat (4456741d2c4fe47a5034db26ad9b1161c24ac18105ca4a71cf23cbe4fc6e3e88)"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:24.277127400Z" level=debug msg="ReleasePool(0.0.0.0/0)"
time="2019-10-31T11:03:24.277127400Z" level=debug msg="daemon configured with a 15 seconds minimum shutdown timeout" time="2019-10-31T11:03:24.278127100Z" level=debug msg="start clean shutdown of all containers with a 15 seconds timeout..."
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default network: hnsCall failed in Win32: The service has not been started. (0x426)
```

But this hns service is running already:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources
λ net start hns
The requested service has already been started.
```

And in Task Manager > Services, I can see hns with Status: Running.

Any idea what's going on?

I've tried

- uninstalling and re-installing docker
- removing Hyper-V and re-adding Hyper-V to Windows,
- added a new virtual switch in Hyper-V,
- I saw something about removing a HNS data file, but there is no such file for me to remove (`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\HNS\` is empty),
- starting and stopping hns service with `net stop hns` and `net start hns`.

I can't think of anything else to try besides just reformatting and starting up a new life with a family in Mexico.

I've uploaded like a thousand crash reports through the Docker for Windows interface, because when the service fails to start, they suggest that. I suspect some guy is very busy ignoring all of those. Obviously I expect nothing will come out of that, since there is no way for me to follow up on them.

**Update 2020**

I still get errors when switching to Windows containers, lol

```
Docker.Core.DockerException:
Error response from daemon: open \\.\pipe\docker_engine_windows: The system cannot find the file specified.

   at Docker.Engines.DockerDaemonChecker.<CheckAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\DockerDaemonChecker.cs:line 40
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.WindowsContainersEngine.<DoStartAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\WindowsContainersEngine.cs:line 52
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 67
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.3.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 92
```

And resetting to Factory Defaults did nothing to fix this: I "reset", switched to Windows containers, and got same error.

**Update 2020 vol. deux**

I found a way to follow up on the crash reports! I created an issue, I've never been so excited in my life.
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/8226

Comment: So, I uninstalled docker, restarted, reinstalled and restarted again. No I seem to get Linux containers working, I can do docker run hello-world and it works.